# Menu bar - fixed vertically, allows horizontal scrolling - without use of scripts

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a site that has a menu bar that remains fixed at the top of the screen.

I have it more or less working as I want, the bar stays where it is. The only problem is that when the window is sized smaller than the menu bar width, it is impossible to horizontally scoll the menu bar (only the content scrolls). This means someone with a small monitor will be unable to use the menu items towards the right.

I've read other questions related to this but the answers all involve scripts, is it possible to achieve a vertically-fixed but horizontally-scrolling menu, using purely css and html? Or do I have to use scripts?

This is the code and relevant css:

html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">Yectlahuilli hC</a>
        </div>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="servicios.html">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <more links...>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="spacer">
</div>
<content...>
```

css:

```
#header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    position:fixed;
    height:134px;
    width:100%;
}
#header > div, #footer > div {
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
#spacer {
position:relative;
height:174px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Any suggestions welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first things that comes to mind is to use css media screens to control the width and height of the menu based on the screen size.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
     #navigation {width: 200px; font-size:12px; and so on...}
}
```

Adjust the max-width to change when the new style come into effect.  Any style that you place in the media screen will take effect when the screen (or window) size is 960px or less.

Comment: if I understand correctly, this would dynamically resize the font and menu bar size if the screen is too small. Is there no way to keep the menu bar the same, and just allow me to horizontally scroll the menu bar if I need to?

Comment: I would need to see the code you are working with but I am pretty sure that the only way to do that is with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What more code should I post? I thought all the relevant information was included above.

Comment: Well you keep saying horizontally.  Do you mean vertically. Up and down?

Comment: Nope, I mean horizontally. I want a bar that stays fixed vertically, but allows me to scroll horizontally. That is, I only want to prevent movement in the up-down direction. Left-right, I want the element to behave like a normal page, that allows scrolling if it doesn't fit into the window

Comment: ok well the only way that I can think of is to use javascript